# rviz segmentation fault on Nvidia Jetson TK1

Tags: ros, rviz, jetson-tk1

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am a beginner to ROS.I have successfully installed ROS indigo on Nvidia Jetson TK1, but the rviz failed to run because of a segfault.  I have checked the article ( http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Troubleshooting ) and tried all the methods including unset GTK_IM_MODULE environment variable,running rviz with the environment variable OGRE_RTT_MODE set to either "Copy", "PBuffer", or "FBO",etc. The segmentation fault error still occurs as below:

```
ubuntu@tegra-ubuntu:~$ rosrun rviz rviz
[ INFO] [949364906.861452095]: rviz version 1.11.7
[ INFO] [949364906.861787179]: compiled against OGRE version 1.8.1 (Byatis)
[ INFO] [949364907.443213679]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[ INFO] [949364907.444094845]: OpenGl version: 4.4 (GLSL 4.4).
Segmentation fault
```

run rviz with "-l"

```
ubuntu@tegra-ubuntu:~$ rosrun rviz rviz -l
[ INFO] [949364916.841945093]: rviz version 1.11.7
[ INFO] [949364916.842273343]: compiled against OGRE version 1.8.1 (Byatis)
[ INFO] [949364917.054474760]: Creating resource group General
[ INFO] [949364917.054978760]: Creating resource group Internal
[ INFO] [949364917.055237676]: Creating resource group Autodetect
[ INFO] [949364917.055584760]: SceneManagerFactory for type 'DefaultSceneManager' registered.
[ INFO] [949364917.056144176]: Registering ResourceManager for type Material
[ INFO] [949364917.056595510]: Registering ResourceManager for type Mesh
[ INFO] [949364917.056888010]: Registering ResourceManager for type Skeleton
[ INFO] [949364917.057175176]: MovableObjectFactory for type 'ParticleSystem' registered.
[ INFO] [949364917.057444843]: OverlayElementFactory for type Panel registered.
[ INFO] [949364917.057695260]: OverlayElementFactory for type BorderPanel registered.
[ INFO] [949364917.057930426]: OverlayElementFactory for type TextArea registered.
[ INFO] [949364917.058175926]: Registering ResourceManager for type Font
[ INFO] [949364917.058447010]: ArchiveFactory for archive type FileSystem registered.
[ INFO] [949364917.058704926]: ArchiveFactory for archive type Zip registered.
[ INFO] [949364917.058785676]: ArchiveFactory for archive type EmbeddedZip registered.
[ INFO] [949364917.058894010]: DDS codec registering
[ INFO] [949364917.059020010]: FreeImage version: 3.15.4
[ INFO] [949364917.059126010]: This program uses FreeImage, a free, open source image library supporting all common bitmap formats. See http://freeimage.sourceforge.net for details
[ INFO] [949364917.059508926]: Supported formats: bmp,ico,jpg,jif,jpeg,jpe,jng,koa,iff,lbm,mng,pbm,pbm,pcd,pcx,pgm,pgm,png,ppm,ppm,ras,tga,targa,tif,tiff,wap,wbmp,wbm,psd,cut,xbm,xpm,gif,hdr,g3,sgi,exr,j2k,j2c,jp2,pfm,pct,pict,pic,3fr,arw,bay,bmq,cap,cine,cr2,crw,cs1,dc2,dcr,drf,dsc,dng,erf,fff,ia,iiq,k25,kc2,kdc,mdc,mef,mos,mrw,nef,nrw,orf,pef,ptx,pxn,qtk,raf,raw,rdc,rw2,rwl,rwz,sr2,srf,srw,sti
[ INFO] [949364917.059652510]: Registering ResourceManager for type HighLevelGpuProgram
[ INFO] [949364917.059771843]: Registering ResourceManager for type Compositor
[ INFO] [949364917.060263593]: MovableObjectFactory for type 'Entity' registered.
[ INFO] [949364917.060380343]: MovableObjectFactory for type 'Light' registered.
[ INFO] [949364917.060491093]: MovableObjectFactory for type 'BillboardSet' registered.
[ INFO] [949364917.060601843]: MovableObjectFactory for type 'ManualObject' registered.
[ INFO] [949364917.060719676]: MovableObjectFactory for type 'BillboardChain' registered.
[ INFO] [949364917.060829843]: MovableObjectFactory for type 'RibbonTrail' registered.
[ INFO] [949364917.061028926]: *-*-* OGRE Initialising
[ INFO] [949364917.061139760]: *-*-* Version 1.8.1 (Byatis)
[ INFO] [949364917.061271926]: Loading library /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/OGRE-1.8.0/RenderSystem_GL
[ INFO] [949364917.068032676]: Installing plugin: GL RenderSystem
[ INFO] [949364917.068307176]: OpenGL Rendering Subsystem created.
[ INFO] [949364917.071679093]: Plugin successfully installed
[ INFO] [949364917.071874760]: Loading library /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/OGRE-1.8.0/Plugin_OctreeSceneManager
[ INFO] [949364917.075039343]: Installing plugin: Octree Scene Manager
[ INFO] [949364917.075288176]: Plugin successfully installed
[ INFO] [949364917.075436760]: Loading library /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/OGRE-1.8.0/Plugin_ParticleFX
[ INFO] [949364917.080376593]: Installing plugin: ParticleFX
[ INFO] [949364917.080617426]: Particle Emitter Type 'Point' registered
[ INFO] [949364917.080830926]: Particle Emitter Type 'Box' registered
[ INFO] [949364917.080996593]: Particle Emitter Type 'Ellipsoid' registered
[ INFO] [949364917.081185426]: Particle Emitter Type 'Cylinder' registered
[ INFO] [949364917.081342760]: Particle Emitter Type 'Ring' registered
[ INFO] [949364917.081469343]: Particle Emitter Type 'HollowEllipsoid' registered
[ INFO] [949364917.081660676]: Particle Affector Type 'LinearForce' registered
[ INFO] [949364917.081855676]: Particle Affector Type 'ColourFader' registered
[ INFO] [949364917.082020426]: Particle Affector Type 'ColourFader2' registered
[ INFO] [949364917.082164260]: Particle Affector Type 'ColourImage' registered
[ INFO] [949364917.082326843]: Particle Affector Type 'ColourInterpolator' registered
[ INFO] [949364917.082461510]: Particle Affector Type 'Scaler' registered
[ INFO] [949364917.082585676]: Particle Affector Type 'Rotator' registered
[ INFO] [949364917.082720593]: Particle Affector Type 'DirectionRandomiser' registered
[ INFO] [949364917.082852676]: Particle Affector Type 'DeflectorPlane' registered
[ INFO] [949364917.082983843]: Plugin successfully installed
[ INFO] [949364917.083166176]: CPU Identifier & Features
[ INFO] [949364917.083342426]: -------------------------
[ INFO] [949364917.083498176]:  *   CPU ID: Unknown ARM
[ INFO] [949364917.084727926]:  *      VFP: no
[ INFO] [949364917.085083676]:  *     NEON: no
[ INFO] [949364917.085443843]: -------------------------
[ INFO] [949364917.085814760]: ******************************
*** Starting GLX Subsystem ***
******************************
[ INFO] [949364917.086205260]: Registering ResourceManager for type Texture
[ INFO] [949364917.086806260]: GLRenderSystem::_createRenderWindow "OgreWindow(0)", 1x1 windowed  miscParams: externalGLControl=  macAPI=carbon parentWindowHandle=62914561 
[ INFO] [949364917.128192343]: GLXWindow::create used FBConfigID = 141
[ INFO] [949364917.128968260]: GL_VERSION = 4.4.0 NVIDIA 19.2
[ INFO] [949364917.129080760]: GL_VENDOR = NVIDIA Corporation
[ INFO] [949364917.129226426]: GL_RENDERER = GK20A/AXI
[ INFO] [949364917.129601426]: GL_EXTENSIONS = GL_AMD_multi_draw_indirect GL_AMD_seamless_cubemap_per_texture GL_ARB_arrays_of_arrays GL_ARB_base_instance GL_ARB_bindless_texture GL_ARB_blend_func_extended GL_ARB_buffer_storage GL_ARB_clear_buffer_object GL_ARB_clear_texture GL_ARB_color_buffer_float GL_ARB_compatibility GL_ARB_compressed_texture_pixel_storage GL_ARB_conservative_depth GL_ARB_compute_shader GL_ARB_compute_variable_group_size GL_ARB_copy_buffer GL_ARB_copy_image GL_ARB_debug_output GL_ARB_depth_buffer_float GL_ARB_depth_clamp GL_ARB_depth_texture GL_ARB_draw_buffers GL_ARB_draw_buffers_blend GL_ARB_draw_indirect GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex GL_ARB_draw_instanced GL_ARB_enhanced_layouts GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility GL_ARB_ES3_compatibility GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location GL_ARB_explicit_uniform_location GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions GL_ARB_fragment_layer_viewport GL_ARB_fragment_program GL_ARB_fragment_program_shadow GL_ARB_fragment_shader GL_ARB_framebuffer_no_attachments GL_ARB_framebuffer_object GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB GL_ARB_geometry_shader4 GL_ARB_get_program_binary GL_ARB_gpu_shader5 GL_ARB_gpu_shader_fp64 GL_ARB_half_float_pixel GL_ARB_half_float_vertex GL_ARB_imaging GL_ARB_indirect_parameters GL_ARB_instanced_arrays GL_ARB_internalformat_query GL_ARB_internalformat_query2 GL_ARB_invalidate_subdata GL_ARB_map_buffer_alignment GL_ARB_map_buffer_range GL_ARB_multi_bind GL_ARB_multi_draw_indirect GL_ARB_multisample GL_ARB_multitexture GL_ARB_occlusion_query GL_ARB_occlusion_query2 GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object GL_ARB_point_parameters GL_ARB_point_sprite GL_ARB_program_interface_query GL_ARB_provoking_vertex GL_ARB_robust_buffer_access_behavior GL_ARB_robustness GL_ARB_sample_shading GL_ARB_sampler_objects GL_ARB_seamless_cube_map GL_ARB_seamless_cubemap_per_texture GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects GL_ARB_shader_atomic_counters GL_ARB_shader_bit_encoding GL_ARB_shader_draw_parameters GL_ARB_shader_group_vote GL_ARB_shader_image_load_store GL_ARB_shader_image_size GL_ARB_shader_objects GL_ARB_shader_precision GL_ARB_query_buffer_object GL_ARB_shader_storage_buffer_object GL_ARB_shader_subroutine GL_ARB_shader_texture_lod GL_ARB_shading_language_100 GL_ARB_shading_language_420pack GL_ARB_shading_language_include GL_ARB_shading_language_packing GL_ARB_shadow GL_ARB_stencil_texturing GL_ARB_sync GL_ARB_tessellation_shader GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp GL_ARB_texture_buffer_object GL_ARB_texture_buffer_object_rgb32 GL_ARB_texture_buffer_range GL_ARB_texture_compression GL_ARB_texture_compression_bptc GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc GL_ARB_texture_cube_map GL_ARB_texture_cube_map_array GL_ARB_texture_env_add GL_ARB_texture_env_combine GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3 GL_ARB_texture_float GL_ARB_texture_gather GL_ARB_texture_mirror_clamp_to_edge GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat GL_ARB_texture_multisample GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two GL_ARB_texture_query_levels GL_ARB_texture_query_lod GL_ARB_texture_rectangle GL_ARB_texture_rg GL_ARB_texture_rgb10_a2ui GL_ARB_texture_stencil8 GL_ARB_texture_storage GL_ARB_texture_storage_multisample GL_ARB_texture_swizzle GL_ARB_texture_view GL_ARB_timer_query GL_ARB_transform_feedback2 GL_ARB_transform_feedback3 GL_ARB_transform_feedback_instanced GL_ARB_transpose_matrix GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra GL_ARB_vertex_array_object GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_64bit GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_binding GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object GL_ARB_vertex_program GL_ARB_vertex_shader GL_ARB_vertex_type_10f_11f_11f_rev GL_ARB_vertex_type_2_10_10_10_rev GL_ARB_viewport_array GL_ARB_window_pos GL_ATI_draw_buffers GL_ATI_texture_float GL_ATI_texture_mirror_once GL_S3_s3tc GL_EXT_texture_env_add GL_EXT_abgr GL_EXT_bgra GL_EXT_bindable_uniform GL_EXT_blend_color GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate GL_EXT_blend_func_separate GL_EXT_blend_minmax GL_EXT_blend_subtract GL_EXT_compiled_vertex_array GL_EXT_Cg_shader GL_EXT_depth_bounds_test GL_EXT_direct_state_access GL_EXT_draw_buffers2 GL_EXT_draw_instanced GL_EXT_draw_range_elements GL_EXT_fog_coord GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample GL_EXTX_framebuffer_mixed_formats GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample_blit_scaled GL_EXT_framebuffer_object GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB GL_EXT_geometry_shader4 GL_EXT_gpu_program_parameters GL_EXT_gpu_shader4 GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil GL_EXT_packed_float GL_EXT_packed_pixels GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object GL_EXT_point_parameters GL_EXT_provoking_vertex GL_EXT_rescale_normal GL_EXT_secondary_color GL_EXT_separate_shader_objects GL_EXT_separate_specular_color GL_EXT_shader_image_load_store GL_EXT_shader_integer_mix GL_EXT_shadow_funcs GL_EXT_stencil_two_side GL_EXT_stencil_wrap GL_EXT_texture3D GL_EXT_texture_array GL_EXT_texture_buffer_object GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1 GL_EXT_texture_compression_latc GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc GL_EXT_texture_cube_map GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp GL_EXT_texture_env_combine GL_EXT_texture_env_dot3 GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic GL_EXT_texture_integer GL_EXT_texture_lod GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias GL_EXT_texture_mirror_clamp GL_EXT_texture_object GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent GL_EXT_texture_sRGB GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode GL_EXT_texture_storage GL_EXT_texture_swizzle GL_EXT_timer_query GL_EXT_transform_feedback2 GL_EXT_vertex_array GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra GL_EXT_vertex_attrib_64bit GL_EXT_x11_sync_object GL_EXT_import_sync_object GL_IBM_rasterpos_clip GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat GL_KHR_debug GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr GL_KTX_buffer_region GL_NV_bindless_multi_draw_indirect GL_NV_bindless_texture GL_NV_blend_equation_advanced GL_NV_blend_equation_advanced_coherent GL_NV_blend_square GL_NV_compute_program5 GL_NV_conditional_render GL_NV_copy_depth_to_color GL_NV_copy_image GL_NV_depth_buffer_float GL_NV_depth_clamp GL_NV_draw_texture GL_NV_ES1_1_compatibility GL_NV_ES3_1_compatibility GL_NV_explicit_multisample GL_NV_fence GL_NV_float_buffer GL_NV_fog_distance GL_NV_fragment_program GL_NV_fragment_program_option GL_NV_fragment_program2 GL_NV_framebuffer_multisample_coverage GL_NV_geometry_shader4 GL_NV_gpu_program4 GL_NV_gpu_program4_1 GL_NV_gpu_program5 GL_NV_gpu_program5_mem_extended GL_NV_gpu_program_fp64 GL_NV_gpu_shader5 GL_NV_half_float GL_NV_light_max_exponent GL_NV_multisample_coverage GL_NV_multisample_filter_hint GL_NV_occlusion_query GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil GL_NV_parameter_buffer_object GL_NV_parameter_buffer_object2 GL_NV_path_rendering GL_NV_pixel_data_range GL_NV_point_sprite GL_NV_primitive_restart GL_NV_register_combiners GL_NV_register_combiners2 GL_NV_shader_atomic_counters GL_NV_shader_atomic_float GL_NV_shader_buffer_load GL_NV_shader_storage_buffer_object GL_NV_texgen_reflection GL_NV_texture_barrier GL_NV_texture_compression_vtc GL_NV_texture_env_combine4 GL_NV_texture_expand_normal GL_NV_texture_multisample GL_NV_texture_rectangle GL_NV_texture_shader GL_NV_texture_shader2 GL_NV_texture_shader3 GL_NV_transform_feedback GL_NV_transform_feedback2 GL_NV_vdpau_interop GL_NV_vertex_array_range GL_NV_vertex_array_range2 GL_NV_vertex_attrib_integer_64bit GL_NV_vertex_buffer_unified_memory GL_NV_vertex_program GL_NV_vertex_program1_1 GL_NV_vertex_program2 GL_NV_vertex_program2_option GL_NV_vertex_program3 GL_NVX_conditional_render GL_NVX_nvenc_interop GL_NVX_shader_thread_group GL_NVX_shader_thread_shuffle GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap GL_SGIS_texture_lod GL_SGIX_depth_texture GL_SGIX_shadow GL_SUN_slice_accum 
[ INFO] [949364917.133240426]: Supported GLX extensions: GLX_EXT_visual_info GLX_EXT_visual_rating GLX_SGIX_fbconfig GLX_SGIX_pbuffer GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap GLX_EXT_buffer_age GLX_ARB_create_context GLX_ARB_create_context_profile GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness GLX_ARB_multisample GLX_NV_float_buffer GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB GLX_ARB_get_proc_address 
[ INFO] [949364917.133565343]: ***************************
[ INFO] [949364917.133777260]: *** GL Renderer Started ***
[ INFO] [949364917.134063343]: ***************************
[ INFO] [949364917.141019510]: Registering ResourceManager for type GpuProgram
[ INFO] [949364917.141417843]: GLSL support detected
[ INFO] [949364917.141652843]: GL: Using GL_EXT_framebuffer_object for rendering to textures (best)
[ INFO] [949364917.146505426]: FBO PF_UNKNOWN depth/stencil support: D0S8 D16S0 D24S0 D32S0 Packed-D24S8 
[ INFO] [949364917.151675593]: FBO PF_L8 depth/stencil support: D0S0 D0S8 D16S0 D24S0 D32S0 Packed-D24S8 
[ INFO] [949364917.158882510]: FBO PF_A8 depth/stencil support: D0S0 D0S8 D16S0 D24S0 D32S0 Packed-D24S8 
[ INFO] [949364917.167745010]: FBO PF_A4L4 depth/stencil support: D0S0 D0S8 D16S0 D24S0 D32S0 Packed-D24S8 
[ INFO] [949364917.176658343]: FBO PF_BYTE_LA depth/stencil support: D0S0 D0S8 D16S0 D24S0 D32S0 Packed-D24S8 
[ INFO] [949364917.183750343]: FBO PF_R5G6B5 depth/stencil support: D0S0 D0S8 D16S0 D24S0 D32S0 Packed-D24S8 
[ INFO] [949364917.192498260]: FBO PF_B5G6R5 depth/stencil support: D0S0 D0S8 D16S0 D24S0 D32S0 Packed-D24S8 
[ INFO] [949364917.202318760]: FBO PF_A4R4G4B4 depth/stencil support: D0S0 D0S8 D16S0 D24S0 D32S0 Packed-D24S8 
[ INFO] [949364917.218564760]: FBO PF_A1R5G5B5 depth/stencil support: D0S0 D0S8 D16S0 D24S0 D32S0 Packed-D24S8 
[ INFO] [949364917.232345176]: FBO PF_R8G8B8 depth/stencil support: D0S0 D0S8 D16S0 D24S0 D32S0 Packed-D24S8 
[ INFO] [949364917.240989343]: FBO PF_B8G8R8 depth/stencil support: D0S0 D0S8 D16S0 D24S0 D32S0 Packed-D24S8 
[ INFO] [949364917.250222176]: FBO PF_A8R8G8B8 depth/stencil support: D0S0 D0S8 D16S0 D24S0 D32S0 Packed-D24S8 
[ INFO] [949364917.262842343]: FBO PF_B8G8R8A8 depth/stencil support: D0S0 D0S8 D16S0 D24S0 D32S0 Packed-D24S8 
[ INFO] [949364917.274027426]: FBO PF_A2R10G10B10 depth/stencil support: D0S0 D0S8 D16S0 D24S0 D32S0 Packed-D24S8 
[ INFO] [949364917.291033926]: FBO PF_A2B10G10R10 depth/stencil support: D0S0 D0S8 D16S0 D24S0 D32S0 Packed-D24S8 
[ INFO] [949364917.300977593]: FBO PF_FLOAT16_RGB depth/stencil support: D0S0 D0S8 D16S0 D24S0 D32S0 Packed-D24S8 
[ INFO] [949364917.310388760]: FBO PF_FLOAT16_RGBA depth/stencil support: D0S0 D0S8 D16S0 D24S0 D32S0 Packed-D24S8 
[ INFO] [949364917.326257093]: FBO PF_FLOAT32_RGB depth/stencil support: D0S0 D0S8 D16S0 D24S0 D32S0 Packed-D24S8 
[ INFO] [949364917.341049510]: FBO PF_FLOAT32_RGBA depth/stencil support: D0S0 D0S8 D16S0 D24S0 D32S0 Packed-D24S8 
[ INFO] [949364917.353136176]: FBO PF_X8R8G8B8 depth/stencil support: D0S0 D0S8 D16S0 D24S0 D32S0 Packed-D24S8 
[ INFO] [949364917.372218843]: FBO PF_X8B8G8R8 depth/stencil support: D0S0 D0S8 D16S0 D24S0 D32S0 Packed-D24S8 
[ INFO] [949364917.387197426]: FBO PF_SHORT_RGBA depth/stencil support: D0S0 D0S8 D16S0 D24S0 D32S0 Packed-D24S8 
[ INFO] [949364917.397985093]: FBO PF_R3G3B2 depth/stencil support: D0S0 D0S8 D16S0 D24S0 D32S0 Packed-D24S8 
[ INFO] [949364917.412038926]: FBO PF_FLOAT16_R depth/stencil support: D0S0 D0S8 D16S0 D24S0 D32S0 Packed-D24S8 
[ INFO] [949364917.424771093]: FBO PF_FLOAT32_R depth/stencil support: D0S0 D0S8 D16S0 D24S0 D32S0 Packed-D24S8 
[ INFO] [949364917.604285426]: FBO PF_FLOAT16_GR depth/stencil support: D0S0 D0S8 D16S0 D24S0 D32S0 Packed-D24S8 
[ INFO] [949364917.612001426]: FBO PF_FLOAT32_GR depth/stencil support: D0S0 D0S8 D16S0 D24S0 D32S0 Packed-D24S8 
[ INFO] [949364917.623415093]: FBO PF_SHORT_RGB depth/stencil support: D0S0 D0S8 D16S0 D24S0 D32S0 Packed-D24S8 
[ INFO] [949364917.628658760]: [GL] : Valid FBO targets PF_UNKNOWN PF_L8 PF_A8 PF_A4L4 PF_BYTE_LA PF_R5G6B5 PF_B5G6R5 PF_A4R4G4B4 PF_A1R5G5B5 PF_R8G8B8 PF_B8G8R8 PF_A8R8G8B8 PF_B8G8R8A8 PF_A2R10G10B10 PF_A2B10G10R10 PF_FLOAT16_RGB PF_FLOAT16_RGBA PF_FLOAT32_RGB PF_FLOAT32_RGBA PF_X8R8G8B8 PF_X8B8G8R8 PF_SHORT_RGBA PF_R3G3B2 PF_FLOAT16_R PF_FLOAT32_R PF_FLOAT16_GR PF_FLOAT32_GR PF_SHORT_RGB 
[ INFO] [949364917.629257176]: RenderSystem capabilities
[ INFO] [949364917.629751926]: -------------------------
[ INFO] [949364917.630205676]: RenderSystem Name: OpenGL Rendering Subsystem
[ INFO] [949364917.635767176]: GPU Vendor: nvidia
[ INFO] [949364917.636131843]: Device Name: GK20A/AXI
[ INFO] [949364917.636461843]: Driver Version: 4.4.0.0
[ INFO] [949364917.636810010]:  * Fixed function pipeline: yes
[ INFO] [949364917.637817093]:  * Hardware generation of mipmaps: yes
[ INFO] [949364917.638175760]:  * Texture blending: yes
[ INFO] [949364917.638497010]:  * Anisotropic texture filtering: yes
[ INFO] [949364917.638830343]:  * Dot product texture operation: yes
[ INFO] [949364917.639209426]:  * Cube mapping: yes
[ INFO] [949364917.640202426]:  * Hardware stencil buffer: yes
[ INFO] [949364917.640572843]:    - Stencil depth: 8
[ INFO] [949364917.640932343]:    - Two sided stencil support: yes
[ INFO] [949364917.641248260]:    - Wrap stencil values: yes
[ INFO] [949364917.641562426]:  * Hardware vertex / index buffers: yes
[ INFO] [949364917.641893093]:  * Vertex programs: yes
[ INFO] [949364917.642264426]:  * Number of floating-point constants for vertex programs: 1024
[ INFO] [949364917.644070593]:  * Number of integer constants for vertex programs: 0
[ INFO] [949364917.646967676]:  * Number of boolean constants for vertex programs: 0
[ INFO] [949364917.647571676]:  * Fragment programs: yes
[ INFO] [949364917.648051010]:  * Number of floating-point constants for fragment programs: 512
[ INFO] [949364917.648497593]:  * Number of integer constants for fragment programs: 0
[ INFO] [949364917.648961093]:  * Number of boolean constants for fragment programs: 0
[ INFO] [949364917.649398426]:  * Geometry programs: yes
[ INFO] [949364917.649852343]:  * Number of floating-point constants for geometry programs: 2048
[ INFO] [949364917.650291176]:  * Number of integer constants for geometry programs: 0
[ INFO] [949364917.650743593]:  * Number of boolean constants for geometry programs: 0
[ INFO] [949364917.651191760]:  * Supported Shader Profiles: arbfp1 arbvp1 fp20 fp30 fp40 glsl gp4fp gp4gp gp4vp gpu_fp gpu_gp gpu_vp nvgp4 vp30 vp40
[ INFO] [949364917.651637260]:  * Texture Compression: yes
[ INFO] [949364917.652077510]:    - DXT: yes
[ INFO] [949364917.652509260]:    - VTC: yes
[ INFO] [949364917.652951593]:    - PVRTC: no
[ INFO] [949364917.653382926]:  * Scissor Rectangle: yes
[ INFO] [949364917.653838926]:  * Hardware Occlusion Query: yes
[ INFO] [949364917.654274176]:  * User clip planes: yes
[ INFO] [949364917.654718343]:  * VET_UBYTE4 vertex element type: yes
[ INFO] [949364917.655155260]:  * Infinite far plane projection: yes
[ INFO] [949364917.655605010]:  * Hardware render-to-texture: yes
[ INFO] [949364917.656056676]:  * Floating point textures: yes
[ INFO] [949364917.656489760]:  * Non-power-of-two textures: yes
[ INFO] [949364917.656938926]:  * Volume textures: yes
[ INFO] [949364917.657641093]:  * Multiple Render Targets: 8
[ INFO] [949364917.658128510]:    - With different bit depths: yes
[ INFO] [949364917.658572510]:  * Point Sprites: yes
[ INFO] [949364917.659025426]:  * Extended point parameters: yes
[ INFO] [949364917.659687426]:  * Max Point Size: 2047
[ INFO] [949364917.660170426]:  * Vertex texture fetch: yes
[ INFO] [949364917.660659343]:  * Number of world matrices: 0
[ INFO] [949364917.661106426]:  * Number of texture units: 32
[ INFO] [949364917.661543176]:  * Stencil buffer depth: 8
[ INFO] [949364917.661996010]:  * Number of vertex blend matrices: 0
[ INFO] [949364917.662435676]:    - Max vertex textures: 32
[ INFO] [949364917.662881510]:    - Vertex textures shared: yes
[ INFO] [949364917.663314176]:  * Render to Vertex Buffer : yes
[ INFO] [949364917.663758093]:  * GL 1.5 without VBO workaround: no
[ INFO] [949364917.664187760]:  * Frame Buffer objects: yes
[ INFO] [949364917.664562926]:  * Frame Buffer objects (ARB extension): no
[ INFO] [949364917.664867843]:  * Frame Buffer objects (ATI extension): no
[ INFO] [949364917.665158010]:  * PBuffer support: yes
[ INFO] [949364917.665464010]:  * GL 1.5 without HW-occlusion workaround: no
[ INFO] [949364917.665768010]:  * Separate shader objects: no
[ INFO] [949364917.666700593]: DefaultWorkQueue('Root') initialising on thread b099f000.
[ INFO] [949364917.667271343]: Particle Renderer Type 'billboard' registered
[ INFO] [949364917.668126510]: SceneManagerFactory for type 'OctreeSceneManager' registered.
[ INFO] [949364917.668478426]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[ INFO] [949364917.668908926]: OpenGl version: 4.4 (GLSL 4.4).
[ INFO] [949364917.672451760]: DefaultWorkQueue('Root')::WorkerFunc - thread aa3cb3b0 starting.
[ INFO] [949364917.680719176]: DefaultWorkQueue('Root')::WorkerFunc - thread aabcb3b0 starting.
[ INFO] [949364917.702747093]: Creating resource group rviz
[ INFO] [949364917.703708843]: Added resource location '/opt/ros/indigo/share/rviz/ogre_media' of type 'FileSystem' to resource group 'rviz'
[ INFO] [949364917.709693760]: Added resource location '/opt/ros/indigo/share/rviz/ogre_media/textures' of type 'FileSystem' to resource group 'rviz'
[ INFO] [949364917.710165510]: Added resource location '/opt/ros/indigo/share/rviz/ogre_media/fonts' of type 'FileSystem' to resource group 'rviz'
[ INFO] [949364917.710582593]: Added resource location '/opt/ros/indigo/share/rviz/ogre_media/models' of type 'FileSystem' to resource group 'rviz'
[ INFO] [949364917.711047676]: Added resource location '/opt/ros/indigo/share/rviz/ogre_media/materials' of type 'FileSystem' to resource group 'rviz'
[ INFO] [949364917.711513176]: Added resource location '/opt/ros/indigo/share/rviz/ogre_media/materials/scripts' of type 'FileSystem' to resource group 'rviz'
[ INFO] [949364917.712176926]: Added resource location '/opt/ros/indigo/share/rviz/ogre_media/materials/glsl120' of type 'FileSystem' to resource group 'rviz'
[ INFO] [949364917.715245593]: Added resource location '/opt/ros/indigo/share/rviz/ogre_media/materials/glsl120/nogp' of type 'FileSystem' to resource group 'rviz'
[ INFO] [949364917.720099093]: Added resource location '/opt/ros/indigo/share/rviz/ogre_media/materials/glsl150' of type 'FileSystem' to resource group 'rviz'
[ INFO] [949364917.721025843]: Added resource location '/opt/ros/indigo/share/rviz/ogre_media/materials/scripts150' of type 'FileSystem' to resource group 'rviz'
[ INFO] [949364917.746612010]: Parsing scripts for resource group Autodetect
[ INFO] [949364917.746863426]: Finished parsing scripts for resource group Autodetect
[ INFO] [949364917.747309260]: Creating resources for group Autodetect
[ INFO] [949364917.747713093]: All done
[ INFO] [949364917.748000510]: Parsing scripts for resource group General
[ INFO] [949364917.748262926]: Finished parsing scripts for resource group General
[ INFO] [949364917.748503093]: Creating resources for group General
[ INFO] [949364917.748725093]: All done
[ INFO] [949364917.748932926]: Parsing scripts for resource group Internal
[ INFO] [949364917.749149760]: Finished parsing scripts for resource group Internal
[ INFO] [949364917.749361760]: Creating resources for group Internal
[ INFO] [949364917.749569343]: All done
[ INFO] [949364917.749792760]: Parsing scripts for resource group rviz
[ INFO] [949364917.751546093]: Parsing script glsl120.program
[ INFO] [949364917.755947426]: Parsing script nogp.program
[ INFO] [949364917.758823676]: Parsing script glsl150.program
[ INFO] [949364917.761125926]: Parsing script indexed_8bit_image.material
[ INFO] [949364917.761730093]: Parsing script point_cloud_tile.material
[ INFO] [949364917.762760343]: Parsing script default_pick_and_depth.material
[ INFO] [949364917.763873760]: Parsing script point_cloud_point.material
[ INFO] [949364917.764765093]: Parsing script point_cloud_sphere.material
[ INFO] [949364917.766350343]: Parsing script point_cloud_square.material
[ INFO] [949364917.767657426]: Parsing script point_cloud_flat_square.material
[ INFO] [949364917.768965843]: Parsing script point_cloud_box.material
[ INFO] [949364917.770350343]: Parsing script arial.fontdef
[ INFO] [949364917.770925593]: Finished parsing scripts for resource group rviz
[ INFO] [949364917.771245593]: Creating resources for group rviz
[ INFO] [949364917.771512176]: All done
[ INFO] [949364917.784020926]: GLRenderSystem::_createRenderWindow "OgreWindow(1)", 100x30 windowed  miscParams: externalGLControl=  macAPI=carbon parentWindowHandle=58720289 
[ INFO] [949364917.792181260]: GLXWindow::create used FBConfigID = 141
Segmentation fault
ubuntu@tegra-ubuntu:~$
```

Could anyone give me clues? Thank you in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212319/rviz-segmentation-fault-on-nvidia-jetson-tk1/) by [redskydeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/22936/redskydeng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 118 on 2015-06-27

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rviz segmentation fault
try to tollow these steps. Its working well for me

$ sudo apt-get remove ros-indigo-robot-model
$ cd ~/catkin_ws/src
$ git clone https://github.com/ros/robot_model.git
$ cd ~/catkin_ws
$ catkin_make
$ source devel/setup.bash

---

Originally posted by [vishu2287](https://answers.ros.org/users/23634/vishu2287/) with karma: 46 on 2015-09-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [redskydeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/22936/redskydeng/) on 2015-12-03**:
Thank you, Vishu2287,
After I did $**sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-robot-model**, this problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

source

echo "unset GTK_IM_MODULE"  >> ~/.bashrc

source ~/.bashrc

rosrun rviz rviz

did you unset in the same bash Window?

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2015-06-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [redskydeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/22936/redskydeng/) on 2015-06-29**:
Thanks for your reply!
I did unset GTK_IM_MODULE in the same bash window and checked it with "echo $GTK_IM_MODULE",the environment variable was empty.The error is as same as before.

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2017-03-30**:
Works for me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Both rviz and collada crash in libpcre3. GTK uses it for IM. Both previous answers are correct.

It's most likely a build server mismatch. Someone should check that the build server is using the latest libpcre3 1:8.31-2ubuntu2.1

Rebuilding collada should fix one issue. Unfortunately you will probably have to rebuild gtk for the other crash.

---

Originally posted by [jolting](https://answers.ros.org/users/18899/jolting/) with karma: 21 on 2015-09-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NStiurca](https://answers.ros.org/users/393/nstiurca/) on 2015-09-11**:
PCRE caused me grief with `robot_state_publisher` on ARM. My workaround is upgrade PCRE packages to version 8.35 from Utopic. See [my other answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/209686/turtlebot-apt-get-update-has-generated-an-error-on-minimallaunch/?answer=217456#post-id-217456) for details.